# Show $A=\{x\in \Bbb{R}^n|\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^p\le 1\}$ is Jordan measurable for $p>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Show $A=\{x\in \Bbb{R}^n|\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^p\le 1\}$ is Jordan measurable if $p>0$. I did show it is a bounded set because if there exists $x^{(N)}\subset A $ such that $||x^{(N)}||\to \infty $ with $N\to \infty$ then there exists $1\le i\le n$ such that from some point $|x_i^{(N)}|\to \infty$ as $N\to \infty$, which means $|x_i^{(N)}|^p\to \infty$, contradicting the criteria of the set.

When it comes to showing that the boundary $\partial A$ is a null set, I get a little confused. Unfortunately, I have a hard time explaining to myself what the boundary is and how to derive it from the inequalities in the criteria of the set mentioned above. I could use any guiding here.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the notion of closure and interior?

Comment: I am. I am just experiencing sudden bewilderment trying to specifically locate the interior.

Comment: Try to draw the set for some specific $n$ and $p$, for instance $n=2$ and $p=1$

Comment: Is it direct that the boundary consists of elements $x$ of $A$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^p=1$?

Comment: Yes, but if you are required more explanation, you can prove that the interior of $A$ is exactly the points for which $\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p < 1$.

Comment: Use the drawing for inspiration: for $x$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|^p<1$, you can call $\epsilon$ the distance between $x$ and the edge (the border) of $A$. Then a ball centered $x$ with radius $\epsilon/2$ only consists of points in $A$, hence $x$ is in the interior.

This cannot be done if $x$ lies on the edge of $A$ because every ball comprises points in the complementary of $A$

Comment: How can I show that the boundary is null? I tried but it seems to me like a non-converging series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35655/discussion-between-octania-and-meitar-abarbanel).